# compare columns of two unsorted file in python....specific output required

Tags: python

I have two pipe delimited files with large data...need to compare their columns..I column is primary key......

eg.
one.dat

```
123|NY|AA|500
569|NY|A|450
777|OK|B|250
899|OK|C|100
```

two.dat

```
569|NY|A+|500
777|OK|A|350
899|OK|B|150
```

Output should be like:

```
NY  column3 1
NY  column4 1
OK  column3 2
OK  column3 2
```

It means for NY records... column III has one difference for matched records..for OK records...column 3 has 2 differennces for matched records....

i want to join two files on I column which is my primary key and then compare their columns.

please help me out :)

Answer (score 1):

If the files are sorted, as the bits of example you show are, you can do it in a way similar to the merge phase of merge sort:

1. You start simultaneously at the beginning of the two files and read a row from each.
2. If their primary keys match, you compare them and output the difference rows you want.
3. If not, you see which of them has the lesser key and move on
   to the next row in that file.
4. Repeat 2 or 3 until you've reached the end of one of the files.

If the files aren't sorted, sort them by primary key first.

Comment: fileHandle = open('one.dat', 'r')

for line in fileHandle:
    fields = line.split('|')